# ACF and PACF functions for AR(2) model

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I am trying to practice calculating the autocovariance function and the partial autocorrelation functions of a time series $X_t$. I am familiar with how to calculate the autocovariance functions of an AR(2) model, but I am not sure how I to go about calculating the autocovariance and partial autocorrelation functions of an AR(2) model such as $X_t=aX_{t-2} +e_t$ where $|a|<1$. Not that here we are missing the $X_{t-1}$ term. Can anybody please help?

Comment: if you can calculate for the generic AR(2) model, why don't you just equate its coefficient to $0$ in the equations you found?

Answer (score -1):

By **Yule-Walker**,
$$ Cov(X_t,X_{t-k}) = aCov(X_{t-2},X_{t-k}) $$
$$ γ(k) = aγ(k-2)$$
divide by $γ(0)$, we get autocorrelation function
$$ ρ(k) = aρ(k-2)$$
We know $ρ(k) = ρ(-k)$ and $ρ(0) = 1$, so that when $k = 1$,
$$ ρ(1) = aρ(1)$$
$$ ρ(1) = 0 $$
and when k = 2,
$$ ρ(2) = aρ(0) = a$$
For $k \geq 3$, we used repeated substitution in $ ρ(k) = aρ(k-2)$